# Publish to Chrome Webstore using the items.Publish API and cURL

Tags: google-chrome, curl, webstore

We are developing a Chrome Extension and, as part of the release build, we want to publish it to the Chrome Webstore for testing.

We are using cURL to send the http requests.

Using the information in :
https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api 
we have successfully updated the store, but I am seeing an odd error when trying to publish it using the information in 
"Publishing an item to trusted testers" in the above link.

The command line looks like this as suggested in the link above:

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer %refresh_token%"  -H "x-goog-api-version: 2" -H "Content-Length: 0"  -H "publishTarget: trustedTesters" -X POST -v https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/%app_id%/publish

When I run this I get an error back stating that the publish condition is not met. The error message states that we should set publish_to_trusted_testers=true, but I can find no documentation suggesting how or where I should set this.

Note that access tokens are working OK, and the PUT command to upload the new extension is also successful.

Any advice would be gratefully accepted.

Jon

Comment: After lots of trial and error, I found that the request needs to have both publish_to_trusted_testers=true and publishTarget=trustedTesters

Comment: Hi Jon, I am facing the exact same problem. But passing both params in header does not fix it. I also tried passing publish_to_trusted_testers=true as data using -d with no luck. I don't know if my call is wrong or if it is because my item in the store is dedicated to trusted testers but with a specific Google Group set. Can you post the curl you used to make it work? Thx!

Comment: Ok I had an invalid target value and finally got it working by removing "publishTarget" and "Content-Length" headers and using `-H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"target":"'$PUBLISH_TARGET'"}'` without `publish_to_trusted_testers=true`

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/items/publish#parameters

The docs on https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api don't currently point to the correct use of the api, but the publish docs are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I tried url query and it succeeded:

```
  curl \
  enter code here-H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"  \
  -H "x-goog-api-version: 2" \
  -H "Content-Length: 0" \
  -X POST \
  -v \
  https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/$APP_ID/publish?publishTarget=trustedTesters
```